# Open/Close SQL Database on the same thread

Tags: android, sql, database

I'm developing a recipe book and I'm implementing this method to insert my Recipe in the Database. In the *for cycle* I get the ingredient's name and quantity from multiples EditText, saving each of them in an **Ingredient.class** instance (*newIngredient*). Then I insert the instance into the DB and add it to an ArrayList. The followings *"if conditions"* are for the title, time and other Recipe's attributes. Finally, I also insert Recipe and Tag instances in the relatives DB's tables and I close DB.

```
public void saveRecipe() {

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    // creating new recipe from user input
    Ingredient newIngredient;
    String title, childIngredient, instruction, tag;
    int target, time, childQuantity, calories;
    int countIngredients = parentIngredientLayout.getChildCount();
    int countTags = chipGroup.getChildCount();
    ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = null;
    ArrayList<Tag> tags = null;
    View childViewIng = null;
    EditText childTextViewI = null;
    EditText childTextViewQ = null;

    // ingredients fields settings
    for (int d=0; d<countIngredients; d++) {
        childViewIng = parentIngredientLayout.getChildAt(d);
        childTextViewI = childViewIng.findViewById(R.id.ingredientsField);
        childTextViewQ = childViewIng.findViewById(R.id.quantityField);
        childIngredient = childTextViewI.getText().toString();
        childQuantity = Integer.parseInt(childTextViewQ.getText().toString());
        newIngredient = new Ingredient(childIngredient, childQuantity);
        dbHelper.insertIngredient(newIngredient);
        ingredients.add(newIngredient);
    }

    //recipe fields settings
    if (photoPath1 == null)
        photoPath1 = "";

    if (photoPath2 == null)
        photoPath2 = "";

    if (photoPath3 == null)
        photoPath3 = "";

    if (titleText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        title = "";
    } else {
        title = titleText.getText().toString();
    }

    if (targetNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        target = 0;
    } else {
        target = Integer.parseInt(targetNumber.getText().toString());
    }

    if (timeNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        time = 0;
    } else {
        time = Integer.parseInt(timeNumber.getText().toString());
    }

    if (instructionText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        instruction = "";
    } else {
        instruction = instructionText.getText().toString();
    }

    if (caloriesNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        calories = 0;
    } else {
        calories = Integer.parseInt(caloriesNumber.getText().toString());
    }

    if (tagName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        tag = "";
    } else {
        tag = tagName.getText().toString();
    }

    Recipe newRecipe = new Recipe(title, photoPath1, photoPath2, photoPath3, instruction, target, time, calories, ingredients);
    Tag newTag = new Tag(tag);

    dbHelper.insertRecipe(newRecipe);
    dbHelper.insertTag(newTag);

    dbHelper.close(); }
```

I found out by debugging that in this case is inserted only the first ingredient. I tried to move the FOR until the end of code, but in that case, are inserted both recipe and tag and always only the first ingredient. I think the problem is relative to the opening/closing of the DB. Can somebody help me?
Ingredient constructor:

```
public Ingredient(String ingredient_name, int quantity) {

    this.ingredient_name = ingredient_name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

dbHelper.insertIngredient(newIngredient) method:

```
public boolean insertIngredient(Ingredient ingredient) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_NAME, ingredient.getIngredient_name());
    contentValues.put(QUANTITY, ingredient.getQuantity());
    contentValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, time.getTime().toString());

    long result = db.insert(TBL_INGREDIENTS, null, contentValues);
    //db.close();
    Log.e(TAG, "Ingredient inserted!");

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi again! can you please add the code of your `Ingredient(childIngredient, childQuantity)` constructor and of your `dbHelper.insertIngredient(newIngredient)` method?

Comment: hi! I edit my answer

Comment: doesn't your Ingredient class have an id? is it auto-generated from db?

Comment: it's auto generated from db. but here I think there's an open/close DB problem. I tried to execute the for cycle in a separated method and it works; instead,  in this situation, db is closing before inserting of others recipe's attributes

Comment: I found out error is in this line: ingredients.add(newIngredient);
error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to your comment we got the problem :)

You are calling `.add(newIngredient)` on a list that you initialized with `ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = null;`

Change it to

```
ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
```

and it will work :)

Good luck!

Comment: I solved just before reading your answer, but I really thank you for helping :)