# SQLite Database for a RecipeApp (one-to-many relationships)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my app I created a Recipe class, an Ingredient class, and a ListIngredient class; then in my DBHelper I created a Recipe table, an Ingredient table, and a ListIngredient table, to link one Recipe to more ingredients, in this way:

```
String RecipeTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TBL_RECIPE + " ( " +
            RECIPE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            RECIPE_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
            RECIPE_FIRST_PHOTO + " TEXT, " +
            RECIPE_SECOND_PHOTO + " TEXT, " +
            RECIPE_THIRD_PHOTO + " TEXT, " +
            RECIPE_TARGET + " INTEGER, " +
            RECIPE_TIME + " INTEGER, " +
            RECIPE_INSTRUCTIONS + " TEXT, " +
            RECIPE_CALORIES + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";
    db.execSQL(RecipeTable);


String IngredientTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TBL_INGREDIENTS + " ( " +
            INGREDIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            INGREDIENT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            QUANTITY + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";
    db.execSQL(IngredientTable);

String ListIngredients = "CREATE TABLE " + TBL_LIST_INGREDIENTS + " ( " +
            INGREDIENT_ID + " INTEGER, " +
            INGREDIENT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            RECIPE_ID + " INTEGER," +
            " FOREIGN KEY ("+RECIPE_ID+") REFERENCES "+TBL_RECIPE+"("+RECIPE_ID+"));";
    db.execSQL(ListIngredients);
```

Then I insert a new Recipe and a new Ingredient with these methods:

```
public boolean insertRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_TITLE, recipe.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_FIRST_PHOTO, recipe.getFirstImage());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_SECOND_PHOTO, recipe.getSecondImage());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_THIRD_PHOTO, recipe.getThirdImage());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_TARGET, recipe.getTargetPeople());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_TIME, recipe.getTime());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_INSTRUCTIONS, recipe.getInstructions());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_CALORIES, recipe.getCalories());
    contentValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, time.getTime().toString());

    long result = db.insert(TBL_RECIPE, null, contentValues);
    //db.close();
    Log.e(TAG, "Recipe inserted!");

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

public boolean insertIngredient(Ingredient ingredient) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_NAME, ingredient.getIngredient_name());
    contentValues.put(QUANTITY, ingredient.getQuantity());
    contentValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, time.getTime().toString());

    long result = db.insert(TBL_INGREDIENTS, null, contentValues);
    //db.close();
    Log.e(TAG, "Ingredient inserted!");

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

But how can I insert into the ListIngredient table the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same you already did for other table, with different column names:

```
public boolean insertListIngredient(ListIngredient listIngredient) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_ID, listIngredient.getIngredientId());
    contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_NAME, listIngredient.getIngredientName());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_ID, listIngredient.getReceipeId());

    long result = db.insert(TBL_LIST_INGREDIENTS, null, contentValues);
    //db.close();
    Log.e(TAG, "ListIngredient inserted!");

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Obv since I don't have your classes I wrote the getters randomly, just change them with correct values and you're done

Edit:

Your `db.insert(...)` method returns the ID of the inserted row, [references](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)). so you can just return it and pass it to your next method, I write here the example for Receipe table:

From reference:

> Returns
>
> long  the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

Insert and return:

```
public long insertRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_TITLE, recipe.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_FIRST_PHOTO, recipe.getFirstImage());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_SECOND_PHOTO, recipe.getSecondImage());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_THIRD_PHOTO, recipe.getThirdImage());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_TARGET, recipe.getTargetPeople());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_TIME, recipe.getTime());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_INSTRUCTIONS, recipe.getInstructions());
    contentValues.put(RECIPE_CALORIES, recipe.getCalories());
    contentValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, time.getTime().toString());

    long result = db.insert(TBL_RECIPE, null, contentValues);
    //db.close();
    Log.e(TAG, "Recipe inserted!");

    return result;

}
```

Method call (example):

```
Receipe mReceipe;
ListIngredient mListIngredient;

// all code
long receipeId = dbHelper.insertRecipe(mReceipe);
if(receipeId != -1){
    mListIngredient.setReceipeId(receipeId);
    dbHelper.insertListIngredient(mListIngredient);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but in my AddRecipeActivity class I have a method to insert ingredients and recipes (you can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379349/open-close-sql-database-on-the-same-thread/55393530?noredirect=1#comment97510751_55393530) and I don't know how to store the IDs of the Recipe and Ingredient

Comment: @EdoardoTavilla edited, let me know if it was clear :)

Comment: You're a hero! :)

Comment: @EdoardoTavilla you're welcome, btw have a look at [realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/).. I really like it for db handling